# Magento - change of product quantity and status is not working in sales_order_place_after event

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have created an event which checks that if the backorder quantity of an item is greater than zero than set the ordered product quantity to zero instead of keeping it in negative and also change its status to out of stock but nothing works.

**config.xml**

```
<sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <some_random>
                        <class>My_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkBackOrder</method>
                    </some_random>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
```

**Observer.php**

```
public function checkBackOrder($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $customer = $order->getCustomer();
            foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
            {
                if ($item->getProductType() == 'simple') {
                    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($item->getProductId());

                    if ($item->getQtyBackordered() > 0) {
                        $webQty = $product->getStockItem()->getQty();
                    if ($webQty <= 0) {
                        $this->_changeStockStatus($product);
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
    }

protected function _changeStockStatus($product)
    {
        $webStockId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getStockId();
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->setStoreId($store)->loadByProduct($product->getId());
        $stockItem->setData('qty', 0);
        $stockItem->setIsInStock(false)->setStockId($webStockId)->save();
    }
```

As you can see in the code that I am not doing something complex except trying to change the item quantity and setting it status to **"Out of stock"** but when I execute this code it does not change the quantity or the status of an item.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time and digging I solved the problem myself. Instead of using `sales_order_place_after` observer I used `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success` which is the last observer running by magento after placing an order.

And this where I placed my code.